# A component is changing an uncontrolled input to be controlled. This is likely caused by the value changing from undefined to a defined value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

So im using Ant design for the form and validation. But I used my own input fields called `FormInput` instead of their `Input`. But now i keep getting this warning. Even though i have set their state and dont have their values as undefined. I then also have handlers that will continuously set their new state. So what the hell is going on??

```
const FormInput = styled.input`
    width: 280px;
    padding: 10px 18px;
    background-color: #E5EBDF;
    color: #545454;
    font-size: 12pt;
    border-radius: 10px;
    outline: none;
    border:none;

    &::placeholder {
        color: #B0B0B0;
    }

    &:hover {
        background-color: #E0E6DA
    }

`


const FormButton = styled.button `
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background-color: #f06e6c;
    color: #FAFFEB;
    margin-top: 5px;

    &:hover {
        background-color: #FF8987
    }
    
`

function Login({history, isAuthenticated, error, login}) {
    // State variables to make input fields controlled components
    const [username, setUsername] = useState("")
    const [password, setPassword] = useState("")

    const onFinish = (values) => {
        console.log('Received values of form: ', values.username, values.password);

    };

    // Fucntions for setting state
    const handleUsername = (event) => {
        setUsername(event.target.value)
    }

    const handlePassword = (event) => {
        setPassword(event.target.value)
    }

    return (
        <LoginForm>
            <Header>Login!</Header>
            <Form
            name="normal_login"
            className="login-form"
            initialValues={{
                remember: true,
            }}
            
            onFinish={onFinish}
            size='large'>
            <Form.Item
                name="username"
                rules={[
                {
                    required: true,
                    message: 'Please input your Username!',
                },
                
                ]}
                // style={{marginBottom: 10}}
            >
                <FormInput placeholder="Username"  value={username} onChange={handleUsername} autoComplete="on"/>

            </Form.Item>
            <Form.Item
                name="password"
                rules={[
                {
                    required: true,
                    message: 'Please input your Password!',
                },
                { min: 5, message: 'Minimum 5 characters.' },
                ]}

            >
                <FormInput placeholder="Password" type="password" value={password} onChange={handlePassword}  autoComplete="on"/>
                
            </Form.Item>

            <div>
                {
                    error &&
                    <Error>Login unsuccessful, <br></br> check username and password</Error>
                }
            </div>
            <Form.Item style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>
                <FormButton htmltype="submit"> Log in </FormButton> Or <FormLink><Link to="/register" className="linkStyle">register now!</Link></FormLink>
            </Form.Item>
            </Form>
        </LoginForm>
    )
}
```

Comment: what is your actual code, where you use these?

Comment: well ill use them in a login function. Prolly shoulve kept that line in. But its right after the console log in the onFinish function. `login(values.username, values.password)` thats it. Cuz its a function i mapped to props from redux. I dont think this matters tho, the login logic works but i keep getting this warning. i prolly should read more about controlled and uncontrolled cuz idek which one i need.